# Naming: dual plural

Tags: list, naming

I encounter this problem with naming several times, and I can't find a definite answer. So, which of underneath naming is correct in English? Assuming that it is name for list of paths to directories.

- `parentDirectoryPaths`
- `parentDirectoriesPath`
- `parentDirectoriesPaths`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it depends on what you want to say.

parentDirectoryPaths: 
There is a parentDirectory and it has multiple Paths. Does not make any sence.

parentDirectoriesPath: 
Many parentDirectories with the same Path (does not make any sence).

parentDirectoriesPaths:
Many parentDirectories with their Paths. Maybe a List of Tupels.

So if you have one parentDirectory it would be parentDirectoryPath.
And if you have many (plural) of them it would be parentDirectoriesPaths

Since only you last example made sence, I'm guessing it is your solution.

Comment: In my current case it's actually list of paths, and each path represents (parent) directory - so your explanation (and chosen option) makes sence. I used to name my lists in similar cases exactly same, I just wasn't sure if it's correct in english.